# can't read property game.state.add() of undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, phaser-framework

I'm trying to make a game using Phaser 3.20.1.

This is my JS code:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(640, 360, Phaser.AUTO);

var GameState = {
  preload: function(){

  },
  create: function(){

  },
  update: function(){

  }
};

game.state.add('GameState', GameState);
game.state.start('GameState');
```

I'm getting an error all time: *"Cannot read property 'add' of undefined"*. Is `game` undefined and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because `game` has no `state` property.

Comment: But class ```Phaser``` must have ```state``` property.

Comment: Having skimmed the docs, I don't think that's correct. Where do you get that information from?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: and Phaser.Game has a ```state``` property: https://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Game.html

Comment: I use 3.20.1 version of Phaser

Comment: Version 3 does not though, `console.log` the variable to convince yourself.

Comment: Really. I should find other tutorials... But thanks!

Comment: The year of the recording could have been a hint ;)